# Scaling and center div issue

Tags: jquery, scale, viewport

I have a `DIV` with `video + overlay + buttons`. So, I need to scale the whole `DIV` to keep everything in place depending the user's viewport dimensions.

So, I made a function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var avH = $(window).height()-20; /* -20 because I have header and footer */
    var avW = $(window).width();
    var scale = Math.min(avW / 300, avH / 200); /* 300 and 200 are the sizes of my original div */
      $('#bdemobox').css({
      transform: 'scale('+scale+')',
    });
  });
```

But instead of being centered, my DIV goes right off the screen when the viewport is too small.

Can you help me please?

https://jsfiddle.net/okv85g5L/

Edit n°1 : I think the centering issue is because it is done with my original DIV dimensions (from the CSS file). So now it looks like this but still not working perfectly :/

```
    var avH = $(window).height()-180;
    var avW = $(window).width();
    var scale = Math.min(avW / 1536, avH / 834);
    var newW = $('#bdemobox').width(); 
    var cke = avW/2-newW/2;
    $('#bdemox').css({
        left:cke,
        transform: 'scale('+scale+')'
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okv85g5L/1/

Comment: Any reason why you're writing jQuery methods to style this and not just using CSS?

Comment: I have no idea how to make it only with css. I need to keep the 1536/834 ratio